# Python mixing asyncio and threading

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

From an architectural perspective, are there any concerns mixing asyncio and threading code?

Example,

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

class ThreadTask:
    def __init__(self, universe_reload_id) -> None:
        self.keep_running = True
        self.universe_reload_id = universe_reload_id


class SomeAlgo:

    def process_universe(self, universe, task):
        while task.keep_running:
            ...

    async def start(self):

        task = None

        universe_reload_id = 1
        for message in self.app_context.kafka_consumer:
            if task:
                task.keep_running = False

            pairs = json.loads(message.value.decode('utf-8'))

            task = ThreadTask(universe_reload_id=universe_reload_id)
            t = Thread(target=self.process_universe, args = (pairs, task))
            t.start() # here we'd call process_universe in non-blocking manner

async def _run_jobs():
    provider = SomeAlgo(param)
    await provider.start()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(_run_jobs())
```

I notice Python has an asyncio version of a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore):
*[Asyncio Semaphore in Python](https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-semaphore/)* vs. *[Threading Semaphore in Python](https://superfastpython.com/thread-semaphore/)*.

So in the above code, which semaphore should/can I use? The asyncio version or the plain version?

Comment: Your example does not show any meaningful use of asyncio.  Your main thread has only one task (_run_jobs) so effectively there is no multitasking.  You might as well just get rid of asyncio and think of this as a basic multithreaded program.  As for your second question, the answer of course depends entirely on what you intend to do with the Semaphore.  There is no Semaphore in your example, so no one can possibly know the answer.